# The results of MPI processes in the script

Tags: ssh, mpi

I want to write an MPI script for using gromacs program, and I wish to change the input data every task(the output for every task will the result of the previous task). I put a piece of the script copying result*.dat to copyfile.sh

```
    cat <<EOF > copyfile.sh
#!/bin/sh
cp -p result*.dat $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
EOF

chmod u+x copyfile.sh
srun -n $SLURM_NNODES -N $SLURM_NNODES cp copyfile.sh $SNIC_TMP

.....
srun -n $SLURM_NNODES -N $SLURM_NNODES copyfile.sh
```

As I am new I got many error messages, so I want to make sure that the tasks work good  first.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be more related to a queue system named SLURM rather than MPI itself. That being said, I don't get the question exactly. Are you possibly asking whether it is possible to chain different MPI executions into a single SLURM job and pass the output of one execution into the next execution?

Comment: First of all I need to know the meaning of that code.
The script is a piece from an example script of message passing (MPI). I can find the input and the output of the process. Now I need to write the right code and get the right output without caring of parallelism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems to be more related to a SLURM job and no MPI code at all.

That being said, the script you posted seem to

> cat < copyfile.sh
>
> #!/bin/sh
>
> cp -p result*.dat $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
>
> EOF

1. Create a copy_file.sh that will copy the result*.dat files from your local disk into $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR directory.

> chmod u+x copyfile.sh

2. Give execution permissions to copyfile.sh so that you can invoke this bash-script.

> srun -n $SLURM_NNODES -N $SLURM_NNODES cp copyfile.sh $SNIC_TMP

3. Spawn on the number of nodes pointed by SLURM_NNODES environment variable a cp command so that to copy the copyfile.sh into the directory $SNIC_TMP

> .....

4. Whatever any other commands not specified.

> srun -n $SLURM_NNODES -N $SLURM_NNODES copyfile.sh

5. Spawn on the number of nodes pointed by SLURM_NNODES environment variable the execution of the copyfile.sh

So after the execution of all these steps, what you should get is to copy the result*.dat files into $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR directory on each computing node assigned to the SLURM job.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to write a script for parallelism in gromacs. I was trying to understand that piece of code. I will soon ask a new question if I need, but I need some time to ask a relative question as I an new to such staff.